# Looking for a better way to do timezone based notifications in Django 3

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'd like to send an email to all users who have not entered a journal entry today. I'd like to give them until 8PM their local time to enter the journal entry, and got this working, but the code is fugly and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to accomplish my goal.

I currently save the user's timezone offset when they sign up.

```
<style>
  #clientTimezone {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    float: left;
  }
</style>

....

<form class="signup form-default row" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="client_timezone" id="clientTimezone" required />

....

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    $('#clientTimezone').val(moment().format('ZZ'))
  })
</script>
```

And then the email code is in my dailyreminder.py management command, which triggers every 10 minutes. I'd like to continue doing this without using celery, if possible.

```
import arrow
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.mail import send_mail, send_mass_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings

from dashboard.models import Entry
from dashboard.emails import email_daily_reminder
from redwoodlabs.models import UserProfile
from identity.strings import GLOBAL_STRINGS

LOCAL_TIME_TO_EMAIL = 20 # 8:00 PM
MAX_LOCAL_TIME_TO_EMAIL = 24 # 12:00 AM
USER_BATCH_SIZE = 10

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Email users daily reminder to reflect'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        # UserProfile model has last_notified (datetimefield) and timezone (char field)

        # get current time in utc
        time_now = arrow.utcnow()

        # Get timezone where it's 8PM
        start_tz = LOCAL_TIME_TO_EMAIL - time_now.hour
        end_tz = MAX_LOCAL_TIME_TO_EMAIL - time_now.hour

        # Get a list of timezones where it is between 8pm to 12am
        timezones = list()
        for tz in range(start_tz, end_tz):
            if tz > 14:
                tz = 24 - tz
                timezones.append('-' + str(tz).zfill(2) + '00')
            else:
                timezones.append('+' + str(tz).zfill(2) + '00')

        time_now_local = time_now.replace(minute=0, second=0)
        time_yesterday = time_now.shift(days=-1)

        # Get all users with the ff cases:
        # - who have not been notified today
        # - who have not been notified at all
        # - who have not been notified in the last 24hrs
        users_to_email = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(last_notified__isnull=True) |
            (Q(timezone__in=timezones) & Q(last_notified__lt=time_now_local.datetime)) |
            Q(last_notified__lt=time_yesterday.datetime)
        ).exclude(timezone__isnull=True)[:USER_BATCH_SIZE]

        for profile in users_to_email:
            user_time_now = time_now.to(profile.timezone)
            user_today = user_time_now.floor('day')
            last_notified_day = arrow.get(profile.last_notified).to(profile.timezone)

            # Send email if last_notified was before today
            if not profile.last_notified or last_notified_day.datetime < user_today.datetime:
                self.stdout.write('Notifying %s' % profile)

                email_sent = email_daily_reminder(profile.user, user_time_now.date())

                # save somewhere they've been notified today?
                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Notified %s' % profile.user.email))
                profile.last_notified = user_time_now
                profile.save()
```

This works (or at least has so far) but I wanted to ask if there's a better way to do this (especially the logic around timezones) because I'll most likely use this code again in a different project and wanted to learn best practices for it. It *seems* like Django has a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has many [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/) that would make your calculations simpler. Basically, what you can try is, annotate your querset with local time / hour of each UserProfile, then do all the necessary calculations on the db level, without the need to construct a list of timezones. Something similar to this could work:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Now
import datetime

users_to_email = UserProfile.objects.exclude(
    timezone__isnull=True
).annotate(
    local_time=ConvertToTimezone(Now(), 'timezone') # Annotate with users' local time
).filter(
    local_time__hour__gte=LOCAL_TIME_TO_EMAIL # Filter to only include users whose local time is past 20 hr
).filter(
    Q(last_notified__isnull=True) | # Not notified at all
    Q(last_notified__date__lt=F('local_time__date')) # Not notified today
).distinct()[:USER_BATCH_SIZE]

for profile in users_to_email:
    self.stdout.write('Notifying %s' % profile)
    email_sent = email_daily_reminder(profile.user, user_time_now.date())
    self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Notified %s' % profile.user.email))
    profile.last_notified = user_time_now
    profile.save()
```

Here, ConvertToTimezone is not a db function available in Django, but the following is a custom db function I have used before for this task:

```
from django.db.models import Func, DateTimeField

class ConvertToTimezone(Func):
    """
    Custom SQL expression to convert time to timezone stored in database column
    """

    output_field = DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, datetime_field, timezone_field, **extra):
        expressions = datetime_field, timezone_field
        super(ConvertToTimezone, self).__init__(*expressions, **extra)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, fn=None, template=None, arg_joiner=None, **extra_context):
        params = []
        sql_parts = []
        for arg in self.source_expressions:
            arg_sql, arg_params = compiler.compile(arg)
            sql_parts.append(arg_sql)
            params.extend(arg_params)

        return "%s AT TIME ZONE %s" % tuple(sql_parts), params
```

I didn't test this code, so its possible it won't work right away, but should give you some hints on using Django's database functions to simplify your code here.